# Splash screen c#

Tags: c#, screen, splash-screen

I'm not so advanced in c# and I make small projects, but now I have a problem. I make a splash screen. Everything work. I make a project with a menu, and in menu you can choose different variants: Encryption, Decrpytion and Exit. In each, I have a "home" button. When I press button, in every menu, every time appear that splash screen and I need to wait. It's annoying. How can I set to work just 1 time (just when I start the program)?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Soft.Properties;
using System.Threading;

namespace Soft
{
    public partial class Meniu : Form
    {
    public Meniu()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashStart));
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        InitializeComponent();

        t.Abort();

    }

    public void SplashStart()
    {
        Application.Run(new LOGO());
    }
```

And one more question. After the Logo appear, the program minimize. Any advice?

Comment: This is rather silly.  You only ever *need* a splash screen when you have to hide the fact that your UI is slow to get started.  The only thing you have to hide is that you put a Thread.Sleep() call in your code and it sleeps entirely too long.  Delete that statement.  Now delete the splash screen since you don't need it anymore.  If you want the user to know who you are then add a Help + About dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want show splash screen only on program starting open your Program.cs and add a counter inside **static class Program** section for count form runs.

> public static int counter=0;

And edit your code like this:

```
public Meniu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Program.counter++;
            if (Program.counter == 1) // If first run minimize and show splash screen
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashStart));
                t.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                t.Abort();
            }
            else // If not first run
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
        }

        public void SplashStart()
        {
           Application.Run(new LOGO());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a run time flag when first time launch, and with a timestamp for next time launch, to indicate that your app has been running, no need to show the splash screen, it just switching between different functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices` namespace. It's available in Winforms projects. This base class provide easy way to add splash screen into your app.